# imageButton setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I have a xml-file. I'm setting OnClickListener for ImageButton btnSeat1,btnSeat2,btnSeat3,btnSeat4. but when i press on it, nothing happens. I've already tried to set clickable, but it didn't work.

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapActivity" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnFilters"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/filter"
                android:onClick="filters_onclick"
                android:text="Мои Фильтры" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCabinet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnFilters"
                android:background="@drawable/kabinet"
                android:onClick="cabinet_onclick"
                android:text="Мой Кабинет" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnCabinet"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnCabinet"
                android:background="@drawable/set"
                android:onClick="settings_onclick" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearShow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/btnCabinet"
                android:background="#c7c8c8"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textfBelowMap"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#c7c8c8"
                    android:text="Быстрый фильтр"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnMapFilter"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/image_open"
                    android:onClick="map_filter" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearS"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/btnCabinet"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linearShow"
                android:background="#c7c8c8"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textBelowM"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#c7c8c8"
                    android:text="Заявок: "
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnMapRequests"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/image_open"
                    android:onClick="request_filter" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnSeat1"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btnCabinet"
                android:background="@drawable/seat1" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnSeat2"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/btnSeat1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/seat2"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnSeat3"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/btnSeat2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/seat3" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnSeat4"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/btnSeat3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/seat4" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnRefresh"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@drawable/refresh"
                android:onClick="refresh_onclick" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnGo"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnRefresh"
                android:background="@drawable/go"
                android:onClick="go_onclick" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnShow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textBelowMap"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnGo"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/after_update_backgound"
                android:text="Отображать только вашего попутчика"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnFinish"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Конец поездки"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textBelowMap"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/btnGo"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Поиск без фильтра осуществляется в радиусе 5км от локации"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="8dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Java-code

```
 btnSeat1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "privet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                LatLng point = new LatLng(coord1_, coord2_);
                if (coord1_ != -1 && coord2_ != -1) {
                    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            point, 17);
                    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                }
            }
        });
```

I'm instantiating like this

```
btnSeat1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSeat1);
        btnSeat2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSeat2);
        btnSeat3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSeat3);
        btnSeat4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSeat4);
```

i'm sure its right, because i can set Image on the buttons.

When i say nothing happens, i mean this. It doesnt crash, it's just not working.
i checked it with debugger, but the breakpoint inside the OnClick can't be reached
Someone said that FrameLayout can be the problem, beacause maybe this buttons are situated on the second layer, maybe thats the problem, but i dont know how to handle it

Comment: Can you describe "but it didn't work."? Does it crash, absolutely nothing happens, etc...

Comment: Could you post your Java where you declare and define the variable btnSeat1?

Comment: show how you instantiate btnSeat1?

Comment: also..r u getting some error in your code.

Comment: @codeMagic ya i missed that..

Comment: it would be very good to see more of Your code. Have You refered the right layout in Your activity? Where did You initialized Your button? If You  get an error, post the logcat..etc...please give us more information to help You

Comment: How did you identify that your code is not working???

Comment: Toast is not showing, and breakpoint can't be reached with debugger

Comment: Use `ActivityName.this' instead of `getApplicationContext()` and say what happend

Comment: i changed. and it all remains the same

Comment: its strange because other buttons are working, except this 4 buttons

Comment: @JenyaKirmiza post your code where you added the onclick lister to the iamge button